# How to set up In App Purchases for Non consumable

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I've set up AdMob ads on my app and want to set up In-App Purchases so that people can pay to disable the ads if they want to. I looked around for some guides on how to do it but they are all for Consumables, none for Non-Consumables. Even the example code that comes with the `in_app_purchase` Flutter package is only about Consumables.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to set up the minimal code just to disable ads in Flutter? I managed to set it up a couple of years back in React Native for consumables and even with guides I remember it was a bit of a nightmare.

I have the In-App Purchase set up in Appstoreconnect already, I just want to know what the actual code needed is. I'm assuming that with just disabling ads the code would be shorter than with consumables.

Comment: Try out this tutorial - https://youtu.be/h-jOMh2KXTA

Answer (score -1):

In the in_app_purchase readme it gives this:

```
final ProductDetails productDetails = ... // Saved earlier from queryPastPurchases().
final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
if (_isConsumable(productDetails)) {
    InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
} else {
    InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's ALL the code required. The code in the example for consumables is huge. Also that code includes code for buying consumables which wouldn't be required for disabling ads only.

Comment: I saw that you had found the example detailing how to purchase a Consumable IAP, so I thought perhaps you had just missed the buyNonConsumable function.

Comment: No, it's not just a single function, there is lots of other code needed to set up. Check a tutorial for IAP consumables in Flutter and you'll see what I mean. IAP is well known for being a terrible pain to set up, that's why there are so many tutorials for it. If only it were as simple as just one function lol....

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to add nonconsumable products in google play console?